# How do I create a restricted AppDomain?

Tags: .net, appdomain

I need to run some user-generated code. Needless to say, I don't want them doing anything interesting like opening files or access web sites. I hear that I can create a locked-down AppDomain that prohibits all this, but I don't know how to set it up.

Answer (score 4):

I've found [an example](http://www.nullify.net/ViewArticle.aspx?article=315) of a Restricted App Domain. This may be enough to get you started.

Comment: Unfortunately this example is a bit not up-to-date now. Most of the calls it uses are marked as `deprecated` or `obsolete`.